# Symfony3 acess control redirect

Tags: symfony

I added @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')") annotation to my function.
When user is not admin then 403 page is appear.
Can I set redirect to home instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect using annotations, you should do it in a controller:

```
    if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }
```